# apt and apt-get upgrading different packages

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, updates

Today I wanted to try out `sudo apt upgrade` instead of `sudo apt-get upgrade`, but for some reason their results differ from each other.

output of `sudo apt upgrade`:

```
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libllvm3.8:i386
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  caribou libcapnp-0.5.3 libinput-bin libllvm4.0 libllvm4.0:i386 libmircommon7 libmircore1 libsensors4:i386 python-dbus python-pyatspi
The following packages will be upgraded:
  gnome-shell gnome-shell-common kmod libappstream-glib8 libegl1-mesa libgbm1 libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libinput10 libkmod2
  libmirclient9 libwayland-egl1-mesa libwhoopsie0 libxatracker2 mesa-vdpau-drivers shim-signed whoopsie
17 upgraded, 10 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 41,4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 123 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
```

output of `sudo apt-get upgrade`:

```
The following packages have been kept back:
  gnome-shell gnome-shell-common libegl1-mesa libgbm1 libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libinput10 libmirclient9 libwayland-egl1-mesa
  libxatracker2 mesa-vdpau-drivers
The following packages will be upgraded:
  kmod libappstream-glib8 libkmod2 libwhoopsie0 shim-signed whoopsie
6 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 11 not upgraded.
Need to get 572 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3.072 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
```

As you can see, `apt-get` only upgrades 6 packages and keeps 11 back whereas `apt` offers to upgrade all 17. Additionally `apt` tries to newly install 10 packages.

I already checked the output of `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt-get update`, but both are using the same package sources.

Now I wonder what this is about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `man apt`:

```
   upgrade (apt-get(8))
       upgrade is used to install available upgrades of all packages
       currently installed on the system from the sources configured via
       sources.list(5). New packages will be installed if required to
       statisfy dependencies, but existing packages will never be removed.
       If an upgrade for a package requires the remove of an installed
       package the upgrade for this package isn't performed.
```

So, for dependencies to be satisfied, `apt` is going to install the new applications.  Where `apt-get` states that `under no circumstances are currently installed packages removed, or packages not already installed retrieved and installed`.  The applications that are being `held back` by `apt-get` you would run it as a `dist-upgrade` instead of `upgrade` as you would do with just the `apt` application.

From `man apt-get`:

```
   upgrade
       upgrade is used to install the newest versions of all packages
       currently installed on the system from the sources enumerated in
       /etc/apt/sources.list. Packages currently installed with new
       versions available are retrieved and upgraded; under no
       circumstances are currently installed packages removed, or packages
       not already installed retrieved and installed. New versions of
       currently installed packages that cannot be upgraded without
       changing the install status of another package will be left at
       their current version. An update must be performed first so that
       apt-get knows that new versions of packages are available.
```

And the descriptions of both:

```
   apt provides a high-level commandline interface for the package
   management system. It is intended as an end user interface and enables
   some options better suited for interactive usage by default compared to
   more specialized APT tools like apt-get(8) and apt-cache(8).

   apt-get is the command-line tool for handling packages, and may be
   considered the user's "back-end" to other tools using the APT library.
   Several "front-end" interfaces exist, such as aptitude(8), synaptic(8)
   and wajig(1).
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ah this explains everything. For example `libxatracker2` is one of the packages that was kept back by `apt-get upgrade` because it depends on `libllvm4.0` but a quick `apt list --installed | grep 'libllvm'` showed me, that I only had `libllvm3.8` installed. `apt upgrade` installed the new dependency and could update the original package.

Comment: @SimonMerkelbach I originally started with the `apt-get` commands, but once I learned what `apt` does instead, I retrained myself to only running `apt` from now on.  I do like the fact that when it upgrades it takes care of the dependencies for me.  =)

Comment: If you're going to downvote, at least explain why you did.

Comment: Just in case you meant me, I upvoted you and don't know why anyone would downvote your answer. It helped me.

Comment: I know you didn't.  :) I have always hoped that when someone downvotes an accepted answer to at least have the decency to explain why they felt they needed to do it.